# Inode of directory on mounted share changes despite no change in modification time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, inode, cifs

I am running Ubuntu 10.4 and am mounting a drive using cifs. The command I'm using is:

'sudo mount -t cifs -o workgroup="workgroup",username="username",noserverino,ro //"drive" "mount_dir"'
 (Obviously with "" values substituted for actual values)

When I then run the command ls -i  I get: 394070 
Running it a second time I get: 12103522782806018

Is there any reason to expect the inode value to change?
Running ls -i --full-time shows no change in modification time.

Answer (score 1):

`noserverino` tells your mount not to use server-generated inode numbers, and instead use client-generated temporary inode numbers, to make up for them. Try with `serverino`, if your server and the exported filesystem support inode numbers, they should be persistent.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the option "nounix" before the "noserverino" kept the inodes small and persistent. I'm not really sure why this happened. The server is AIX and I'm running it from Ubuntu. Thank you for your response.